# Table problems. Should I recreate and simplify the table with createElement and appendChild methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, uitableview

PROBLEM 1:
I cannot get imported array variables to stay as the array changes throughout use. The slice method creates a new array to my understanding and when I use a function on a button to slice the array and change the table itself, I send the sliced element above and remove it from the table. On function use, the button changes to a second function that does the same, but sends the second sliced out element up top and slices another element from the table.

QUESTION 1:

When I slice the array the second time it changes the first initial sliced element.

TABLE AND SCRIPT FORMAT:

I have a Top area where values that are removed from the table and selected are sent above as it's removed.

```
 <div class='top-stick'>
    <button style='width:50px; height: 50px'>X</button>
    <p id='selectOne' style='text-align: center; background-color: lightgreen; border: solid 3px black; padding: 5px'>First Perk Selected</p>
    <p id='selectTwo' style='text-align: center; background-color: lightgreen; border: solid 3px black; padding: 5px'>
Second Perk Selected</p>
    <p id='selectThree' style='text-align: center; background-color: lightgreen; border: solid 3px black; padding: 5px'>
Third Perk Selected </p>
    <p id='percenttotal' style='text-align: center; background-color: lightgreen; border: solid 3px black; padding: 5px'>Craft %</p>
  </div>
<div>
```

above is the is the top section that receives the values chosen by the button.

```
<table id='myTable' style='background-color: lightgreen; padding: 5px'>
  <tr>
    <th style='width: 20px'> Click Box to Select Perk</th>
    <th style='width: 100px'>Perk</th>
    <th>Effect</th>
    <th class='percent' style='width: 40px'>Craft %</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='background-color: black; width: 75px'> 
      <button id='myBtn' value='1'>Select</button>
    <td id='perkOne'></td>
    <td id='perkOneEffect'></td>
    <td id='perkOnePercent'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='background-color: black'>
      <button id='myBtn'> Select </button>
    <td id='perkTwo'></td>
    <td id='perkTwoEffect'></td>
    <td id='perkTwoPercent'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='background-color: black'>
      <button id='myBtn'> Select </button>
    <td id='perkThree'></td>
    <td id='perkThreeEffect'></td>
    <td id='perkThreePercent'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this is the table but it goes all the way up to 26 rows.

below is the function that imports all the variables into the empty table by Id before any buttons are pressed.

```
function importBefore() {
document.getElementById("perkOne").innerHTML = perkName[0];
document.getElementById('perkTwo').innerHTML = perkName[1];
document.getElementById('perkThree').innerHTML = perkName[2];
document.getElementById('perkFour').innerHTML = perkName[3];
document.getElementById('perkFive').innerHTML = perkName[4];
document.getElementById('perkSix').innerHTML = perkName[5];
document.getElementById('perkSeven').innerHTML = perkName[6];
document.getElementById('perkEight').innerHTML = perkName[7];
document.getElementById('perkNine').innerHTML = perkName[8];
document.getElementById('perkTen').innerHTML = perkName[9];
document.getElementById('perkEleven').innerHTML = perkName[10];
```

This is the button function that slices an array and modifies the display of the table while sending the removed array value to the above portion.

```
function first() {
var perkNameOne = perkName.slice(0, 26)
document.getElementById('selectOne').innerHTML = perkNameOne[0];
perkName = perkName.slice(1, 26);
perkEffect = perkEffect.slice(1, 26);
perkPercent = perkPercent.slice(1, 26);
document.getElementById('selectedFirst').innerHTML = null;
importFirst();
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  second();
});
}
```

I import the table itself then use a button to slice and import new values then change the button function at the end of each button press with a reset button at the top left.

The problem I am having is that

```
var perkNameOne = perkName.slice(0, 26)
document.getElementById('selectOne').innerHTML = perkNameOne[0];
```

this value changes with each button press that goes along even though

```
perkName = perkName.slice(1, 26);
```

I never slice perkNameOne again. To my understanding, slicing creates a new array...? I may need to remake the table and simplify it with an automatic createElement and appendChild method that creates rows based on length of array.

perkNameOne[0] changes to the newly sliced array further down the strip.

PROBLEM 2:

I also can't change perkName[0] to

```
  let n = "";
for (let i = document.getElementById(myBtn).value; i = perkName; i) {
  n = perkName[i];
```

or however that coding line goes. so I can write the button as-

```
<button id='myBtn' value='0'>Select</button>

<button id='myBtn' value='1'>Select</button>

function slice(a)  {
  return slice(a);
}

function first(document.getElementById('myBtn').this.value) {
var perkNameOne = perkName.slice(a, 26)
document.getElementById('selectOne').innerHTML = perkNameOne[0];
perkName = perkName.slice(a, 26);
perkEffect = perkEffect.slice(a, 26);
perkPercent = perkPercent.slice(a, 26);
document.getElementById('selectedFirst').innerHTML = null;
importFirst();
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  second();
});
}
```

and use the value of each line in itself instead of having 26 different functions on each button.

QUESTION FOR PROBLEM 2:

Not sure how I can get each button to slice the element out of the row it is in on the table so that I wouldn't have to make a different function and event listener for every single button.

I'm new to coding and this is my first complex interactive data-table.

Comment: Would it be easier to understand if I just imported the table and functions as a whole instead of breaking it down? it is quite large so i thought breaking it down and putting the important segments in would make it simpler to understand.

also, I edited OP, not sure if this will help you understand my question.

Comment: I will try the document.querySelector method and change the array names and see if that works.
I have limited use of the document.querySelector codeline. I'll see if I can make it work then give an update, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please fix the question, its very difficult to understand in the current format.
Here are a few tips:

- use `document.querySelector` instead.
- use plural words for values like arrays, and singular words for singular

  - `perkNames` instead of `perkName`
  - then `perkName` when you need to refer to a single perk's name
  - don't use spelled out numbers, it makes things more complex than needed.
  - you can swap the html ids with html classes, then select it inside js with `document.querySelector('.perk:nth-child(1)')` or something like this `document.querySelector('.perks-container>:nth-child(1)')`